# Join Dataframes on columns with similar but not exact values

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas dataframes that I want to join on employee_id.  One is Employee_Logs the other is HR_Data.

Employee_Logs_df

```
employee_id  action
2325255b     login     
51666164     login
51666164v    login
r1211        logoff
r18552421    login
```

HR_Data_df

```
employee_id  name
2325255      Rob    
51666164     Tom
r1211        Tammy
r18552421    Ron
```

I want to join them so that the data looks like this:

New_df

```
employee_id  action  name
2325255b     login   Rob  
51666164     login   Tom
51666164v    login   Tom
r1211        logoff  Tammy
r18552421    login   Ron
```

I could do an easy join if the employee_id field matched up on both tables, but the same user can have a "`b`" or a "`v`" after their employee id to specify if the account is elevated like an admin account.  Some user accounts have an "`r`" in front of the id but that is the case in both tables.

In SQL this gives me the desired results:

```
select el*,
    coalesce(h.name, hv.name, hb.name) as name
from employee_logs el left join
    hr_data h
    on el.employee_id = h.employee_id left join
    hr_data hv
    on el.employee_id = concat(h.employee_id, 'v') left join
    hr_data hb
    on el.employee_id = concat(h.employee_id, 'b');
```

Is there a good way in Python where I can do some where actions and create a new df?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can strip the trailing letter from `employee_id` in `Employee_Logs_df` using a regex, then map that to your names from `HR_Data_df`:

```
new_df = Employee_Logs_df.assign(name = Employee_Logs_df.employee_id
                                 .str.extract('(.*\d+)',expand=False)
                                 .map(HR_Data_df.set_index('employee_id')['name']))

>>> new_df
  employee_id  action   name
0    2325255b   login    Rob
1    51666164   login    Tom
2   51666164v   login    Tom
3       r1211  logoff  Tammy
4   r18552421   login    Ron
```

You can do something very similar with a merge if you wanted:

```
new_df = Employee_Logs_df.merge(HR_Data_df.set_index('employee_id'),
                                left_on=Employee_Logs_df.employee_id
                                .str.extract('(.*\d+)',expand=False),
                                right_index=True)

>>> new_df
  employee_id  action   name
0    2325255b   login    Rob
1    51666164   login    Tom
2   51666164v   login    Tom
3       r1211  logoff  Tammy
4   r18552421   login    Ron
```